# Excel Formula to Word

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-word-2013

I have this formula to give me a specific day of the week.

```
=TODAY()-(WEEKDAY(TODAY())-2)
```

How would I set this up in Microsoft Word 2013

Comment: Will this link help you?. I see the formula can be used when the data fed into the tables. Please check. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8ea152/mathematical-formula-in-word-2013/

Comment: The issue is for Number Format what do you enter?

Comment: It depends on what you mean - Word does not understand Excel formulas, so the only way to use them in Word is to embed or link an Excel workbook that contains the formula. Both techniques have problems. Word's own formula fields don't have support for dates, but you can use macropod's date fields to work around that - see datecalc.zip on, e.g. http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm (although that is an old version). Or you can use a bit of VBA to insert the date, or use it to populate a document variable whose value you insert with a { DOCVARIABLE } field.